# Prompt for filename for screenshot

Tags: file-management, screenshots

I have an S7 with Android 8 and Samsung Experience 9

Is there a way to be prompted for a filename when you take a screenshot?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Android built in screenshot function does not support to specify the filename.

One alternative way for triggering a screenshot would be to use `adb shell` via USB or Wifi from a connected PC. On the shell you can execute `screencap /sdcard/screenshot1.png` and therefore specify the filename.